# how to change the language?

Tags: languages

I'm writing an article mainly in armenian language and use for it  `\usepackage{armtex}`. But in the middle of text I want to change it to english, but it doesn't work and continues to write armenian letters.
I've tried using babel but it gives me error like this

```
Package babel Error: Unknown option `armenian'. Either you misspelled it

(babel)                or the language definition file armenian.ldf was not found.
```

also I've tried the commands like `\foreignlanguage{english}` , `\select@language{english}` but they didn't work.
I also use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
How can I do it? please help.

Comment: Please provide a MWE. Are you using only `armtex` or also `babel`? In the first case, doesn't `\aroff` work for you? Not that I use `armtex`, I just read the docs.

Comment: I use the following packages
\usepackage{armtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
but when I want to write english it just writes english word with armenian letters, I want to change the language in the middle of the text.
I'm afraid I can't use babel because I get errors with that

Comment: ooh now I understand. \aroff works ! thank you ... and how can I continue with the main language after that?

Answer (score 1):

To use Armenian as your main language in Babel, add the command

```
\babelprovide[import, main]{armenian}
```

to your preamble.  I believe you’re still supposed to load English through the package option, `usepackage[english]{babel}`.

### Update

This got bumped back to the front page, so I’ll provide an example.  This requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[import, main]{armenian}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }

\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{Gentium}
%% The Arain AMU fonts are available from:
%% http://arian.tarumian.am/?page_id=34&lang=en
\babelfont[armenian]{rm}{Arian AMU Serif}
\babelfont[armenian]{sf}{Arian AMU}
\babelfont[armenian]{tt}{Arian AMU Mono}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % Allow more interwordd space in ugly paragraphs

\begin{document}
\section*{ՄԱՐԴՈՒ ԻՐԱՎՈՒՆՔՆԵՐԻ ՀԱՄԸՆԴՀԱՆՈՒՐ ՀՌՉԱԿԱԳԻՐ}

Բոլոր մարդիկ ծնվում են հավասար ու անօտարելի իրավունքներով և հիմնական ազատություններով։

Միավորված ազգերը պարտավորություն է ստանձնել պահպանել, խրախուսել ու պաշտպանել յուրաքանչյուր անհատի մարդու իրավունքները։ Այս պարտավորությունը բխում է Միավորված ազգերի կանոնադրությունից, որը վերահաստատում է աշխարհի ժողովուրդների հավատը մարդու հիմնական իրավունքների, անձի արժանապատվության ու արժեքի նկատմամբ։

Մարդու իրավունքների համընդհանուր հռչակագրում Միավորված ազգերի կազմակերպությունը պարզ ու հասկանալի ձևով ներկայացրել է այն իրավունքները, որոնք հավասարապես պատկանում են յուրաքանչյուր մարդու։

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
The above should be an excerpt from the UN Declaration of Human Rights.
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arian AMU Serif sample]

In LuaLaTeX, if you remove the `[english]` option and change the `\babelprovide` line to

```
\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=ids fonts]{armenian}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}
```

you will be able to type in either language, and LuaTeX will detect the language you are using.  It will change fonts and hyphenation patterns accordingly.

Comment: sorry but  \babelprovide[import, main]{armenian}  doesn't work...

Comment: @Ani You also would need to load an Armenian font, but the exact details would depend on which engine and packages you want to use.